# NullPointerException in inflating layout

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I'm getting NullPointerException in my code when I'm inflating layout.

This is my java code-

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grouped_text_view, this);
itemsContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_container);
itemsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);           //line 1
```

grouped_text_view.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/GroupedTextViewContainer">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/items_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/item_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

These are the logs-

```
08-02 13:44:05.870: W/System.err(500): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  com.drindia.groupedtextviewcustom.GroupedTextView.initialize(GroupedTextView.java:67)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  com.drindia.groupedtextviewcustom.GroupedTextView.<init>(GroupedTextView.java:45)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
08-02 13:44:05.880: W/System.err(500):  at  android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
08-02 13:44:05.890: W/System.err(500):  at  com.devrepublic.kommaaropmetjeaanbieding.ui.InformationActivity.onCreate(InformationActivity.j ava:23)
```

Comment: So what does LogCat say about your exception?

Comment: I'v added the logs. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

Instead of using `context` use directly `LayoutInflator class` as shown below:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grouped_text_view, null);
itemsContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_container);
itemsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: My class is extending LinearLayout so can't use getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) directly.